# How do I get the following page layout using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want my layout to be like the image below

[image: Page demonstration: header, menu, submenu to left, main content area, and footer]

This is the code that I have tried:

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #faf8f6;
    font-family:'Segoe UI', Verdana, Arial;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #2c2c2c;
}
img, img a, img a:hover {
    border: none;
}
p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#main-wrapper {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
#header {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #faf8f6;
}
#left-logo {
    margin: 38px 0 26px 35px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 36px;
    float: left;
}
#left-logo p {
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 26px;
}
#left-logo p span {
    color: #d4102b;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#right-logo {
    margin: 15px 35px 15px 0;
    width: 217px;
    height: 70px;
    float: right;
}
#menu-wrapper {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 28px;
    background-color: #948e8a;
    border-top: 1px solid #5a4736;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #5a4736;
}
#body-wrapper {
    top: 130px;
    bottom: 25px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
#left-menu-wrapper {
    width: 199px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #948e8a;
    border-right: 1px solid #5a4736;
}
#content-wrapper {
    width: calc(100%-200px);
    margin: 0 0 0 200px;
    height: 100%;
}
#footer {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 24px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #948e8a;
    border-top: 1px solid #5a4736;
    position: fixed;
}
#footer p {
    margin: 0 35px 0 0;
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="main-wrapper">
            <div id="header">
                <div id="left-logo">
                    <p><span>123</span> India</p>
                </div>
                <div id="right-logo">
                    <img src="Css/Images/logo.gif" />
                </div>
                <div class="clr"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="menu-wrapper"></div>
            <div id="body-wrapper">
                <div id="left-menu-wrapper"></div>
                <div id="content-wrapper"> </div>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                <p>&copy; 2013. 123India. All rights reserved.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

And here's a [live demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5jpH/) on JS Fiddle.

Comment: What browser support do you need?

Comment: sooo, what's your problem?

Comment: so, you've got it working. what now??

Comment: It works for me too. Are you using IE? It's a dangerous virus, you know? :D

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go about this imo, is fixed divs for the headers, sidebar and footer. Then one main div which pushes the body to make it scrollable. You (at least I do) want native scrolling and should avoid scrollable divs with set heights.

Benefits over pushing the body instead of using a scrollable content div:

- the entire document is scrollable, instead of just the content div
- you won't have issues with -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch and any hardware acceleration issues that come along with it (e.g. relatively positioned elements on a scrollpane, image tearing, ...)

Here's how I solved it:

```
<div id="header">head</div>
<div id="header2">head2</div>
<div id="sidebar">side</div>
<div id="content">
    1st that's a lotta stuff!<br />that's a lotta stuff!<br />that's a lotta stuff!<br />that's a lotta stuff!<br />that's a lotta stuff!<br />that's a lotta stuff!<br />that's a lotta stuff!<br />that's a lotta stuff!<br />that's a lotta stuff!<br />that's a lotta stuff!<br />that's a lotta stuff!<br />that's a lotta stuff!<br />that's a lotta stuff!<br />that's a lotta stuff!<br />that's a lotta stuff!<br />that's a lotta stuff!<br />that's a lotta stuff!<br />that's a lotta stuff!<br />that's a lotta stuff!<br />that's a lotta stuff!<br />that's a lotta stuff!<br />that's a lotta stuff!<br />that's a lotta stuff!<br />that's a lotta stuff!<br />that's a lotta stuff!<br />that's a lotta stuff!<br />that's a lotta stuff!<br />that's a lotta stuff!<br />that's a lotta stuff!<br />that's a lotta stuff!<br />that's a lotta stuff!<br />that's a lotta stuff!<br />that's a lotta stuff!<br />that's a lotta stuff!<br />that's a lotta stuff!<br />that's a lotta stuff!<br />that's a lotta stuff!<br />    
</div>
<div id="footer">foot</div>
```

And for the css:

```
body, html{
    margin: 0
}

#header, #header2, #sidebar, #footer{
    border: 1px solid black;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0
}

#header, #header2, #footer{ right: 0 }

#header {    
    background-color: lightblue;
    height: 100px 
}

#header2 {    
    background-color: lightyellow;
    border-top-width: 0;
    height: 30px;
    top: 100px
}

#sidebar { 
    background-color: lightgreen;
    border-top-width: 0;
    border-bottom-width: 0;
    top: 130px;
    width: 200px; 
    bottom: 30px
}

#content {
    padding-left: 200px;
    padding-top: 130px;
    padding-bottom: 30px
}

#footer {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 30px
}
```

Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/kevinsmets/d5bpL/